# Lie Bracket Properties

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $X,Y\in\Xi(M)$ are two vector fields. Is it true that

> If $\gamma(t)$ is a curve such that $X|_{\gamma(t)}=0$ then
>   $[X,Y]|_{\gamma(t)}=0$

By now I have the feeling that it is false but I don't know how to prove it in a formal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. Consider for example $X = y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then

$$ X(Yf) - Y(Xf) = X \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) - Y \left( y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) = y \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} - \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}\right) = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $$

and so $[X,Y] = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ which is a non-vanishing vector field. If you take $\gamma(t) \equiv (0,0)$ then $X(\gamma(t)) = X((0,0)) = 0$ but $[X,Y]|_{(0,0)} \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you @levap . Is it false for the same reason that if $p\in M$ is such that $X(p)=Y(p)=0$ then $[X,Y](p)=0$?

Comment: @GSF: I don't really understand your comment. What you wrote is true! That is, if $X(p) = Y(p) = 0$ then $[X,Y](p) = 0$ for the integral curve of $X$ passing through $p$ is constant and so $[X,Y](p) = \frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t(p)^{-1}(Y(\varphi_t(p)))|_{t = 0} = \frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t(p)^{-1} (Y(p))|_{t = 0} = \frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t(p)^{-1}(0)|_{t = 0} = \frac{d}{dt} 0|_{t = 0} = 0$ where $\varphi_t(p)$ is the flow determined by $X$. In the example I cooked above, $p = 0$ and $X(p) = 0$ so the integral curve is constant but $Y(p) \neq 0$ and so $[X,Y] = \frac{d}{dt} \varphi_t(p)^{-1}(Y(p))$

Comment: but the point is that $\varphi_t$ is a non-trivial diffeomorphism near $p$ and so $d\varphi_t \colon T_p M \rightarrow T_p M$ is an interesting linear map (that is not the identity) and so, when you differentiate it you get something interesting.